# What's design pattern should I use to generalize similar classes usage?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

I have some device classes like the following sample:

```
public class MoveSensor() {
     public uint GetData() {
         // Some logic here
     }
}

public class TemperatureSensor {
     public double GetData() {
         // Some logic here
     }
}

public class MultiSensorUnit() {
     public MultiSensorData GetData() {
         // Some logic here
     }
}

public class MultiSensorData {
    public int SomeSensor1Data { get; set; }
    public byte SomeSensor2Data { get; set; }
    public double SomeSensor3Data { get; set; }
}
```

Yet I have a class to periodically collect a data from these devices:

```
public class DataCollector() {
     public void CollectData() {
         // Here I want to collect a data from all devices
     }
}
```

Looks like I should use an interface:

```
public interface IDataRecievable {
    [This is a problem place] GetData();
}
```

But I can't do it because GetData() returns different types from different devices. I need a design pattern to make usage of devices in DataCollector more universal and generic.

Comment: Is it the same logic or different logic in the sensors, im guessing different, interfaces seems like a worthy solution

Comment: I'm not really sure what you expect here. You could define a generic interface, e.g. `IDataGetter<T>`, and then make the method generaic, e.g. `T GetData();` and then have each class fix `T` differently, e.g. `public class TemperatureSensor : IDataGetter<double>`.  That doesn't really help though because each of your `GetData` methods is still going to be returning a different type so you would need to cast each return value as that type to use it.

Comment: jmcilhinney, please type your code in answer textarea, comments are not for answers and code snippets. I just see that devices have the same method GetData() and I feel that exist a way to optimize a code, make it more scalable and universal.

Comment: What do you end up doing with the data (logging it, display to user, etc.) and how often does polling occur?

Comment: There isn't enough implementation detail in this question to provide a reasonable answer.  It looks like a bunch of properties that return different types and you want to somehow aggregate all that data in one place.  You could go `dynamic` I guess.  Or you may need something far more advanced.  I can't say with just some `GetData` methods that look like they can be converted to properties.

Comment: @pepeevich That's not really an answer.  It's a guess at what you could try, but would likely come up short.  Also when addressing someone in comments make sure you put the @ before the name so they get notified.

Comment: P.Brian.Mackey, I want to work with all devices in DataCollector the same way, because they are similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all of your sensors returning different kinds of data, you may consider move your data processing into each sensor implementation.
If you can do that, here is how I would implement it.

Declare an interface

```
public interface IDataRecievable<T>
{
    T GetData();
    void CollectData();
}
```

And concrete classes:

```
public class MoveSensor : IDataRecievable<uint>
{
    public void CollectData()
    {
        //do collect logic here
    }

    public uint GetData()
    {
        //do get data
    }
}

public class TemperatureSensor : IDataRecievable<double>
{
    public void CollectData()
    {
        //do collect logic here
    }

    public double GetData()
    {
        //do get data
    }
}
```

And data collector class

```
public class DataCollector
{
    public void CollectData()
    {
        var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        .Where(type => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
        .Where(type => type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType 
                        && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDataRecievable<>)));

        foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic sensor = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            sensor.CollectData();
        }
    }
}
```

I get all classes implement IDataRecievable<>, create an instance and call the CollectData() method. You can always call GetData() isstead of CollectData() if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could encapsulate the functionality of the returned data into various implementations of the same interface. For example, if the data will be displayed, each sensor returns a different type that displays the data in a different way. For example:

```
public interface Sensor {
    Data GetData();
}

public interface Data {
    void Display();
}

public class IntData : Data {
    public void Display() { ... }
}

public class DoubleData : Data {
    public void Display() { ... }
}

public class MoveSensor : Sensor {
    public IntData GetData() {
        // ... return IntData ...
    }
}

public class TemperatureSensor : Sensor {
    public DoubleData GetData() {
        // ... return DoubleData ...
    }
}
```

Then some client can iterate through each sensor and display the data:

```
List<Sensor> sensors = // ...

foreach (Sensor sensor in sensors) {
    sensor.Display();
}
```

This is not restricted to displaying the data, the `Data` interface can incorporate any type of functionality. For example, if the data needed to be stored into a database, you can pass some proxy to the database to a method and each `Data` implementation would know how to store itself in the database:

```
public class DatabaseProxy {
    public void StoreInt(int value) { ... }
    public void StoreDouble(double value) { ... }
}

public interface Data {
    void StoreData(DatabaseProxy proxy);
}

public class IntData : Data {

    private int _value;

    public IntData(int value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public void StoreData(DatabaseProxy proxy) {
        proxy.StoreInt(_value);
    }
}

public class DoubleData : Data {

    private double _value;

    public DoubleData(double value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    public void StoreData(DatabaseProxy proxy) {
        proxy.StoreDouble(_value);
    }
}
```

The idea is to shift the responsibility of using the returned data away from some external entity and hand it to the data itself. Ergo, the `Data` implementation is closest to the data it is storing and thus, it should be responsible for handling it. If there are too many things that need to be accomplished by `Data`, then more complex techniques can be used, like handlers or callbacks to separate the data from the handling of data.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the results of each sensor are going to be. You have given examples of a uint and a double. I guess other sensors could in theory return strings or even complex compound objects.

The answer from a sensor is meaningless without knowledge of what that sensor measures, and that would obviously be known to the consumer of this data. Is your problem in the intermediate storage in DataCollector?

I can imagine Dictionary where you would want to hold an arbitrary number of sensors and their results. Can you live with the boxing/unboxing performance overheads? If there isn't a massive number of sensors then this should be negligible. If so, you can do something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public interface IDataRecievable 
{
    object GetData();
}

public class PiSensor : IDataRecievable
{
     public object GetData() {
         return (object)3.14m;
     }
}

public class StringSensor : IDataRecievable
{
     public object GetData() {
         return (object)"Hello World";
     }
}


public class DataCollector
{

   private List<IDataRecievable> sensors;

   private Dictionary<Type, object> sensorResults = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

   public DataCollector(IEnumerable<IDataRecievable> sensorsToPoll)
   {
       this.sensors = sensorsToPoll.ToList();
   }

   public T GetResultFromSensor<T>(Type sensorType)
   {
      return (T)this.sensorResults[sensorType];
   }

    public void CollectData()
    {
        foreach (IDataRecievable sensor in this.sensors)
        {
            sensorResults[sensor.GetType()] = sensor.GetData();
        }           
    }    
}

public class Program
{       
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<IDataRecievable> sensors = new List<IDataRecievable>
        {
            new PiSensor(),
            new StringSensor()
        };          
        DataCollector dc = new DataCollector(sensors);    
        dc.CollectData();           
        decimal pi = dc.GetResultFromSensor<decimal>(typeof(PiSensor));
        string greeting = dc.GetResultFromSensor<string>(typeof(StringSensor));

        Console.WriteLine(2 * pi);
        Console.WriteLine(greeting);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also probably go with Trung Le's implementation, but I would also have some interface for giving the result of the collecion:

```
public interface ICollectResultReceiver
{
    void ReceiveCollectResult(
        // whatever you are storing
        object someData
    );
}
```

I would also use another interface for the collection process, because it feels like data collection isn't a part of getting data:

```
public interface IDataRecievable<T>
{
    T GetData();
}

public interface IDataCollectable
{
    void CollectData(ICollectDataResultReceiver resultReceiver);
}
```

This way the user of `IDataCollectable` classes don't need to care about the types, and just use a for loop to run all the collection.

```
public interface IDataCollector
{
    void Add(IDataCollectable collectable);
    void CollectData();
}

public class DataCollector : IDataCollector
{
    private readonly ICollectDataResultReceiver _resultReceiver;
    private readonly List<IDataCollectable> _collectables = new List<IDataCollectable>();

    public DataCollector(ICollectDataResultReceiver resultReceiver)
    {
        _resultReceiver = resultReceiver;
    }

    public void Add(IDataCollectable collectable)
    {
        _collectables.Add(collectable);
    }

    public void CollectData()
    {
        foreach(var collectable in _collectables)
        {
            collectable.CollectData(_resultReceiver);
        }
    }
}
```

Other than that, I would also make interfaces for each sensor, because there are times where knowing what kind of module you're using is necessary.

```
public interface IMoveSensorDataReceivable : IDataReceivable<uint> { }
public interface ITemperatureSensorDataReceivable : IDataReceivable<double> { }
public interface IMultiSensorDataReceivable : IDataReceivable<MultiSensorData> { }
```

So `MultiSensorData` would be more visible of what kind of data it has.

```
public class MultiSensorData
{
    public uint GetSensorData1() => _moveSensor.GetData();
    public double GetSensorData2() => _temperatureSensor.GetData();

    private readonly IMoveSensorDataReceivable _moveSensor;
    private readonly ITemperatureSensorDataReceivable _temperatureSensor;

    public MultiSensorData(
        IMoveSensorDataReceivable moveSensor, 
        ITemperatureSensorDataReceivable temperatureSensor)
    {
        _moveSensor = moveSensor;
        _temperatureSensor = temperatureSensor;
    }
}
```

It is also important to use interfaces instead of concrete classes for better testing. Even though `MultiSensorData` doesn't need much testing, your tests would be like so:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Fact]
    public void MultiSensorDataTest()
    {
        var dummyTempSensor = new DummyTempSensor();
        var dummyMoveSensor = new DummyMoveSensor();
        var multiSensorData = new MultiSensorData(dummyMoveSensor, dummyTempSensor);

        Assert.Equal(10, multiSensorData.GetSensorData1());
        Assert.Equal(0.5, multiSensorData.GetSensorData2());
    }

    private class DummyTempSensor : ITemperatureSensorDataReceivable
    {
        public double GetData() => 0.5;
    }

    private class DummyMoveSensor : IMoveSensorDataReceivable
    {
        public uint GetData() => 10;
    }
}
```